# "NSArray' does not have a member named 'append'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsarray

I just got into swift coding and I am trying to follow a tutorial. but it seems as if the coder I'm following may have an older version, or I am doing something wrong. I am trying to make a sound object to make a soundboard. but when i try to add the sound file to the array using append, it says that the method `append` is not a member of the `NSArray`. can someone tell me what is the right way to do solve this?!][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3leoq.jpg)

[image]

Comment: You should work with Swift native type Array

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Declare sounds as

```
var sounds: [Sound] = []
```

Answer (score 11):

You should work with Swift native type Array

```
var array: [Any] = []
```

if you know it will have only one type you can do as follow:

```
var intArray: [Int] = []
var doubleArray: [Double] = []
var stringArray: [String] = []
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift and Foundation arrays are different types of objects. 
Swift `Array` declares a method called `append`,  `NSMutableArray`(`NSArray` is immutable you can't modify it after you created) doesn't declare that kind of method.
The solution is cast your `NSArray` into an `Array` type (using the `as` operator, since they are bridged), or use the method `-addObject:` on a `NSMutableArray`, but first you need to make a `-mutableCopy` of the `NSArray`

Answer (score 1):

`NSArray` is an immutable object.
You have to use `NSMutableArray` Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/)

Comment: even `NSMutableArray` will return same error. Shouldn't it be a type of inbuilt datatype `array`

Comment: The method you have to use is `addObject:`