# How do I start with an empty attributedString whenever the UITextView changes?

Tags: ios, swift, character, uitextview, nsmutableattributedstring

I am using attributed string to format a single character string for `UITextView` that will update whenever a button is clicked or a picker is moved. However, because I use `attributedStringLine.append(attributedCharString)` the `attributedString` continues to grow rather than start a new attributed string whenever `UITextView`is updated.

The code *below* demonstrates a simplified version of the problem.

`NSMutableAttributedString()` operates on the string in `myArray`. New strings are processed whenever `UITextView` changes. These are in `array1,` `array2` and `array3`.

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

let array1                      = ["7.0", "55.55", "1.0", "9.27"]
let array2                      = ["0", "10", "20", "30", "40"]
let array3                      = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

var myArray                     = [""]
let attributedStringLine        = NSMutableAttributedString()
let numberOfRawStringCharacters = myArray.count


func appendTextString(i: Int){
    let rangeOfCharString       = (myArray[i] as NSString).range(of: myArray[i])
    let attributedCharString    = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: myArray[i], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: UIFontWeightLight)])
    attributedCharString.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blue], range: rangeOfCharString)
    attributedStringLine.append(attributedCharString)
}


func makeText() {
    for i in 0..<myArray.count {
        appendTextString(i: i)
    }
}

var line = attributedStringLine.length

myArray.removeAll()
myArray                         = array1
myArray.count
makeText()
print(attributedStringLine)
line = attributedStringLine.length

myArray.removeAll()
myArray                         = array2
myArray.count
makeText()
attributedStringLine
line = attributedStringLine.length

myArray.removeAll()
myArray                         = array3
myArray.count
makeText()
attributedStringLine
line = attributedStringLine.length
```

How do I start with an empty attributedString whenever the `UITextView` changes ?

For `NSMutableString`, replacing or deleting characters from the range of an existing attributed string seems to be the only alternative available. And I'm pretty sure this is not a duplicate of [Value of type 'NSMutableAttributedString' has no member 'removeAll'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30474680/2348597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declared `attributedStringLine` with `let`, you can remove all character from it at the start of `makeText`.

```
func makeText() {
    attributedStringLine.deleteCharacters(in: NSMakeRange(0, attributedStringLine.length))
    for i in 0..<myArray.count {
        appendTextString(i: i)
    }
}
```

Or you change its declaration from `let` to `var` and then use `attributedStringLine = NSMutableAttributedString()` at the start of `makeText`.

Comment: Your first solution worked fine in my Xcode project so from my point of view it will be the accepted answer. It’s worth noting that in Playground attributed strings appear correctly formatted for `array2` and `array3`, but for `array1` the unformatted string appears followed by the attributed formatting script enclosed in curly brackets. On the Simulator these numeric floating point characters display correctly. Thanks.